# Delete file from sub folder but want to exclude one sub folder-batch file

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I have parent folder name parent, inside parent folder there are `subfolder01`, `subfolder02` and `default` folders.

Each folder contains one `jar` file with same name (`abc.jar`). I want to delete `jar` file  from `subfolder01` and `subfolder02` not from `default` folder.

How to exclude `default` folder when giving cmd like `del /s *.abc.jar`?

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? `del /S` hasn't got any exclusion option, so you 'll need to script it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `for` loop with `/F` option, which will allow the loop to parse the output of `dir` command. A possible solution:

**batch-file:**

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%A IN ('dir "parent_folder" /b /s /A:D') do set "my_var=%%A" && if "!my_var:\default\=!"=="!my_var!" (del !my_var!\abc.jar)
```

**cmd**

```bat
cmd /v:on
for /f "delims=" %A IN ('dir "parent_folder" /b /s /A:D') do set "my_var=%A" && if "!my_var:\default\=!"=="!my_var!" (del !my_var!\abc.jar)
```

Comment: yes it's working for me now. Thank you very much all your help!